# Product of 2 couples of complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Let $a, b, c, d$ be complex numbers, but such that

$b = \displaystyle \frac{a}{k}, d = \displaystyle \frac{c}{k}$ with $k$ real.

Moreover,

$$ab^* = \frac{|a|^2}{k} = cd^* = \frac{|c|^2}{k} = r$$

Where $b^*$ is the complex conjugate of $b$ and so on.

Is it possible to prove that

$$ad^* = cb^* = r$$

?

Thank you anyway!

Comment: What does $b*$ mean?

Comment: complex conjugate of $b$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Counterexample:

$$b=e^{i\phi_1}, d=e^{i\phi_2}\quad\Rightarrow\quad a=ke^{i\phi_1},c=ke^{i\phi_2}$$

gives

$$ad^*=ke^{i(\phi_1-\phi_2)}\quad\textrm{and}\quad cb^*=ke^{i(\phi_2-\phi_1)}$$

both of which are not real if $\phi_1-\phi_2\neq \pi n,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$.